# How to use FORMATTED_VALUE in a cumulated graph?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

At first, from the Data Render panel in icCube report, I used `context.cumulativeCol();` in the `Value` field in order to create my cumulated graph.

Now, since the format of my data is not well suited for my application (I have values such as '4.547473508864641e-13' which I want to be formatted to 0.00), I tried to add parameters to the function :

`var col = context.getColumnIndex();
 var measure = context.getMeasures();
 var property = "FORMATTED_VALUE";
 return context.cumulativeCol(col, measure, property);`

But I cannot get a proper output.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use FORMATTED_VALUE to format numbers calculated on the client side, it's available on for data that comes directly from the server. So in your case you need to implement your own client-side formatting. You could use [mathJS](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/format.html) that bundled to the reporting i.e.:

```
return math.format(context.cumulativeCol(col), {notation: "fixed", precision: 2})
```

Or use any other JS formatting method like .toFixed(2)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed.